# Does Stripe instant payout allow for an instant charge to payout?

Tags: stripe-payments

I've been attempting to use Stripe Instant Payout to go from charge to a payout in "mere moments" as documented here : https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payouts#instant-payouts

This has proved to be confusing and difficult.

I currently have a Stripe account with a "Connect"ed Stripe profile. I create the charge for the Connect user, (which has an instant pay valid card) and then I create the payout. When I go to payout, using the method [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payouts#instant-payouts), it fails, saying the balance isn't available.

Why is this? The balance is in pending, but the docs state "You can pay out an account’s available balance plus its *pending* balance"

Comment: Strange, are you definitely passing `method=instant`? It's probably best to speak to Stripe's support(https://support.stripe.com/email) about this.

Comment: @Newah did you ever figure this out?  Running into the same issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@Newah when you place a charge to a Stripe Connect account that charge is not available for payout immediately. You can check when the charge will be available for payout using the balance transaction object https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance/balance_transaction. You can also get this when retrieving a charge by expanding the balance transaction.

```
{
  "id": "txn_19XJJ02eZvKYlo2ClwuJ1rbA",
  "object": "balance_transaction",
  "amount": 999,
  "available_on": 1483920000,
  "created": 1483315442,
  "currency": "usd",
  "description": null,
  "exchange_rate": null,
  "fee": 59,
  "fee_details": [
    {
      "amount": 59,
      "application": null,
      "currency": "usd",
      "description": "Stripe processing fees",
      "type": "stripe_fee"
    }
  ],
  "net": 940,
  "source": "ch_19XJJ02eZvKYlo2CHfSUsSpl",
  "status": "available",
  "type": "charge"
}
```

The charge will be available for payout on the timestamp set in `available_on`.

Comment: I understand that, but that doesn't explain the explicit use of "instant" in the documentation (US only) https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payouts#instant-payouts